# Driver for Sharp Photocopier AR-5620N

Tags: drivers, printing

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I need a printer driver for Sharp AR-5620N.

Comment: Please specify what steps do you have done. Did you tried to connect it to computer and simply run `system-config-printer` wizard? FYI - previous AR-5220 seems to be [well supported](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Sharp/Sharp-AR-5220) by `pxlmono` driver.

Comment: printer is connected to a LAN which is running microsoft windows. when i try to add printer, asks for the driver. I've tried ar-5220 ppd file but its not working.

Comment: i simply click add printer and in network printer i can see printer name & IP. when i click it shows default printer drivers and there is no driver for AR-5620N.is there any other way?.iam new to this Linux.

Comment: You can try this network way. I'm sorry, I do not own any Sharp devices. You can try to use search here on AskUbuntu or on Ubuntu and/or Debian forums.